# Xcode Continuous Integration - "iOS Simulator failed to install the application"

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, ios-simulator

Running into an odd problem: integrations sometimes fail with this:

> Test target [...] encountered an error (iOS Simulator failed to
>   install the application.)

We test with two simulators, 7.0 and 7.1.

I tried opening the simulators on the server and clearing their contents through the ui. I also tried to delete the ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone/Simulator/7.xx/Applications data with no result.

What is frustrating is the integration process works for a few hours, then breaks with the mentioned failure message, then works.

I've looked at the logs, but no smoking gun, but I might have missed something.

Where should I be looking to debug this?

If this is just a special case of all the other questions about **iOS Simulator failed to install the application**, then I'd imagine I'd need the ability to run a clean up script. How can I hook into the integration process?

**Update:** I'm manually running this command before every integration:

```
rm -rfv ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/;
```

with the same results. I sometimes get "iOS Simulator failed to install..."

I have also tried clearing out the simulators manually through the ui. I still get the issue.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation. While I haven't solved it yet, Xcode bots (service) use this directory for simulators `/var/_xcstest/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/` not `~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/`

Comment: @Chris, Danedo, have you solved this issue?

Comment: @sidslog restarting the server inconsistently solves the issue. I have not found a complete solution as of yet. I even received the same error today.

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve the issue by assigning a non-empty value to Bundle versions string, short (CFBundleShortVersionString) in the -Info.plist file. iOS 7 doesn't like an empty value for the build number. You can have a script that auto increments the bundle number by 1 every time you build the project so this field was empty. You can also assign a dummy value there to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Try: "IOS Simulator->Reset Content and Setting".